# Operating on abstract filters (list comprehension): Combining two filters

Tags: filter, lua, set, list-comprehension

**Short and sharp:**
Given two Boolean statements, what is the easiest way to calculate the equation of their intersection in a language like Lua?

[image: Venn Diagram]
(Red = Filter 1, Blue = Filter 2, Purple = Area of intersection)

**Long and lamenting:**

- **Filter A**: `object.ID < 300`
- **Filter B**: `object.ID < 600`

**Filter A** is a *subset* of **Filter B**, that is: **Filter B** will contain everything matched by **Filter A**, plus 0 or more objects.
On a Venn diagram, **Filter A** would be inside **Filter B**.

How can I calculate the equation of the area of intersection?

A more complicated example:

- **Filter X**: `object.Col == 'GREEN' and (object.ID == 2 or object.ID == 64 or object.ID > 9001)`
- **Filter Y**: `(object.Col == 'RED' or object.Col == 'GREEN') and (object.ID == 3 or object.ID > 22)`

**Filter A** intersects with **Filter B**.
On a Venn Diagram, they would overlap.
The equation for the overlapping area would be:
`object.Col == 'GREEN' and (object.ID == 64 or object.ID > 9001)`

How would this equation be calculated in a language such as Python or Haskell?

I wish to eventually make this in Lua, but if Python, Haskell or another language provided the functionality, I would be able to look at the source code and convert it over.

Here is how I am representing filters in Lua:

```
filter = DataFilter(
    {"and",
        {"or",
            {"==", "Col", "RED"},
            {"==", "Col", "GREEN"},
        },
        {"or",
            {"==", "ID", 3},
            {">" , "ID", 22},
        },
    }
)
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess: Bring the "Filters" into disjunctive normal form and reduce using appropriate methods (x == 8 contained in x > 5).

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I'm researching into it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is somehow you can achieve this. The self commented code would help you understand the approach

```
#Create a Class Foo with attributes id and col
class Foo:
    def __init__(this,ID,COL):
        this.id=ID
        this.col=COL



#Dataset
data=["VIOLET","INDIGO","BLUE","GREEN","YELLOW","ORANGE","RED"]
ObjList=[Foo(random.randint(1,70),random.choice(data)) for i in xrange(1,10000)]

#Create the Filter Functions
def FilterX(obj):
    return obj.col == 'GREEN'  and (obj.id == 2 or obj.id == 64 or obj.id > 9001)

def FilterY(obj):
    return (obj.col == 'RED' or obj.col == 'GREEN') and (obj.id == 3  or obj.id > 22)

def FilterZ(obj):
    return obj.col == 'GREEN'  and (obj.id > 50)

#Create a list of filter functions
filters=[FilterX,FilterY,FilterZ]

#Create a set result (that will hold the intersected data) and assign the result of
#applying the First Filter on ObjList
result=set(filter(filters[0],ObjList))

#For the Rest of the filter's apply them on the ObjList, and then intersect
#the resultant set with the result
for s in (set(filter(foo,ObjList)) for foo in filters[1:]):
    result=result.intersection(s)

#Finally Display the result
[(obj.id,obj.col) for obj in result]
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code. Although this is needed eventually, it is not what I am asking for in the question; I need the equation of the resulting set, not the set itself. Definitely worth a vote up, though :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm missing an important point here. It seems that your filters just return a boolean depending on the qualities of "object". Why don't you just use regular "and" and "or"s and functions to compose them?

This is how I'd make your filters in Lua:

```
function filterX(object)
  return object.Col == 'GREEN' and 
    (object.ID == 2 or object.ID == 64 or object.ID > 9001)
end

function filterY(object)
   return (object.Col == 'RED' or object.Col == 'GREEN') and 
     (object.ID == 3 or object.ID > 22)
end
```

You can define the "union" or "intersection" of those filters with these extra functions:

```
function union(f,g)
  return function(...)
    return f(...) or g(...)
  end
end

function intersection(f,g)
  return function(...)
    return f(...) and g(...)
  end
end
```

And here's how you compose:

```
union(filterX, filterY)(object) -- returns true or false
intersection(filterX, filterY)(object) -- true or false
```

Or, if you want to reuse them often:

```
filterXorY = union(filterX, filterY)
filterXandY = intersection(filterX, filterY)

filterXorY(object) -- true or false
filterXandY(object) -- true or false
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need the resulting expression of `filterXandY`, which cannot be obtained from Lua without a binary module (or string.dump) and some nasty hacks. Also, it would not be simplified. Also, there would be no way to determine whether Filter X and Filter Y intersect or are mutually exclusive, unless some brute-force looping through all the possible objects was performed.

Comment: I see. Have you considered using math-oriented languages, like Mathematica, R or similar, instead of a generic programming language? They should have most of what you need built-in.